# Shortest posts on a Stack Exchange site by body length with username of original poster (SEDE)

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

So I recently have been working on a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1823198/shortest-posts-on-a-site-less-than-50-characters) that outputs posts from a given Stack Exchange site that have bodies of less than 50 characters.

While I have figured out how to get the links to those posts, I would also like to get the usernames under which those questions were posted.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT p.Id AS [Post Link], Len(Body) AS [Body Length], p.Score, p.ViewCount, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
WHERE Len(Body) < 50
AND p.PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY Len(Body) DESC
```

What I have tried to do to get my desired result:

- While `p.OwnerUserId` does produce a new column, it only produces the given user IDs, while I would like the username specifically.
- However, if I change `p.OwnerUserId` to `p.OwnerDisplayName`, this only produces a blank column with nothing in it.
- It also seems like if I try to call `u.OwnerDisplayName`, it produces the error
  `Line 1: The multi-part identifier "u.OwnerDisplayName" could not be bound.`

My question is: How can I also get the username of the original poster of the questions into its own column?

---

Revisions that include previous attempts (if it would be helpful to look at):

- [2216057](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1823198/2216057/shortest-posts-on-a-site-less-than-50-characters)/[2216049](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1823198/2216049/shortest-posts-on-a-site-less-than-50-characters)
- [2216048](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1823198/2216048/shortest-posts-on-a-site-less-than-50-characters)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383297/908824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join to the `Users` table:

```
SELECT p.Id          AS [Post Link]
     , u.DisplayName
     , len(p.Body)   AS [Body Length]
     , p.Score
     , p.ViewCount
     , p.Tags
  FROM Posts p
           join
       Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
 WHERE len(p.Body)  < 50
   AND p.PostTypeId = 1
 ORDER BY len(p.Body) DESC
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` might be wiser in case user has been deleted.